# GeoNetwork LDAP group extraction from user's attribute

Tags: authentication, geonetwork

In our LDAP we have user attribute `memberOf` witch indicates what groups a user is a member of. The value of `memberOf` attribute represented by full group DN. Here is the example:

`memberOf` = `CN=PROJ_Admins_GeoNetwork,OU=PROJ,OU=Groups,OU=ORG,DC=org-it,DC=com`

I want to set up GeoNetwork to automatically generate groups for user based on `memberOf` value. Here is section for that in `config-security-overrides.properties`:

```
# Map user information to LDAP attributes and default values
ldapUserContextMapper.mapping[name]=givenName,
ldapUserContextMapper.mapping[surname]=sn,
ldapUserContextMapper.mapping[mail]=mail,data@myorganization.org
...↓
ldapUserContextMapper.mapping[privilege]=privileges,sample
ldapUserContextMapper.mapping[profile]=profile,RegisteredUser
```

I need to set: `ldapUserContextMapper.mapping[privilege]={user's attribute with groups from LDAP},{default group name}`

So I ended up with: `ldapUserContextMapper.mapping[privilege]=memberOf,default_group`

But **the problem** is that I don't want the entire value of `memberOf` to be the name of created GN groups. I just need a part after `CN=` and before `,OU=PROJ...`:

`memberOf` = CN=**PROJ_Admins_GeoNetwork**,OU=PROJ,OU=Groups,OU=ORG,DC=org-it,DC=com

**My question is**: can I use regular expression or LDAP queries in the `config-security-overrides.properties` and what should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/4.0.x/en/administrator-guide/managing-users-and-groups/authentication-mode.html#privileges-configuration) about LDAP privileges configuration.

You will need to enable the `LDAPUserDetailsContextMapperWithPattern` in `WEB-INF/config-security/config-security-ldap.xml` commenting out the default `ldapUserContextMapper`. Then in [`WEB-INF/config-security/config-security.properties`](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/3.12.7/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config-security/config-security.properties#L62-L69) define `ldap.privilege.pattern`, `ldap.privilege.pattern.idx.group` and `ldap.privilege.pattern.idx.profil`:

```
ldap.privilege.pattern=CN=([^_]+_([^_]+)_[^_,]+).*
ldap.privilege.pattern.idx.group=1
ldap.privilege.pattern.idx.profil=2
```

The first capturing group is capturing the full group name, for example for `CN=PROJ_Admins_GeoNetwork,OU=PROJ,OU=Groups,OU=ORG,DC=org-it,DC=com` it's capturing `PROJ_Admins_GeoNetwork`. The second capturing group is capturing the profile, in this example `Admins`. To make GeoNetwork understand this group it should be one of `Administrator`, `UserAdmin`, `Reviewer`, `Editor` or `RegisteredUser` instead of `Admins`

Comment: Thank you for the regex and describing steps! Is there a way to skip not valid role names like `Admins` and set default `RegisteredUser` profile defined after comma in `config-security-overrides.properties` : `ldapUserContextMapper.mapping[profile]=memberOf,RegisteredUser` ? My user have multiple groups, some of them I configured to contain `Administrator`, but some still contains other words. When I logging GN show me that error:

```
MESSAGE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.fao.geonet.domain.Profile.Admins
```

Comment: Is there a way to extract group from LDAP user's property with regex and ignore profile (set default one)?